# Are there any costs for Google Nearline / Coldline bucket item enumeration?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I want to use Google Coldline to store backups of customer files. To upload only the new files, I'll have to enumerate all the existing files in my Google Storage bucket and then compare the list to the contents of local folder.

In Google's documentation I found that custom metadata incurs additional costs calculated the same way as data access of stored objects themselves.

But what about object names? If I often read the list of names of all objects in a bucket, will this operation add to the data access costs or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing the names of bucket and objects are [Class A Operations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-by-class) and are [charged by batches of 10,000 operations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing). Frequent get requests will increase your data costs.